# How to select the first date and last date of each block in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the table:

| date | phase | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.20 | a | 10 |
| 2.1.20 | a | 10 |
| 3.1.20 | b | 10 |
| 4.1.20 | a | 10 |
| 5.1.20 | a | 10 |
| 6.1.20 | b | 10 |

I need to return for each user_id the start date and end date for each phase when a contains all the phases in the middle and b is the end phase, without using window functions.
Should look like this:

| user_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1.1.20 | 3.1.20 |
| 10 | 4.1.20 | 6.1.20 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Comment: *without using window functions* Why

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO. Never use 2 digit years!

Answer (score 1):

Without using window functions.
You can do a self-join to the table.
Then calculate a rank/group for the phases.
Then it's simple to group by the user and the phase group.

> ```
> select user_id
> , min([date]) as start_date
> , max([date]) as end_date
> from
> (
>   select t1.user_id, t1.[date], t1.phase
>   , count(t2.phase) as grp
>   from your_table t1
>   left join your_table t2
>     on t2.user_id = t1.user_id
>    and t2.phase = 'b'
>    and t2.[date] >= t1.[date]
>   group by t1.user_id, t1.[date], t1.phase
> ) q
> group by user_id, grp
> order by user_id, start_date
> ```

| user_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03 |
| 10 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-06 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f30f83650ab6cb46e649d73f9450d679)*

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte1 as(
        select user_id,date,
         case
           when phase = 'a' and (lag(phase)over(order by date) is null or lag(phase)over(order by date) = 'b') 
            then 1
            else 0
          end grp
        from tb),
cte2 as(
    select user_id,date, sum(grp)over(order by date) as rnk
    from cte1)
select user_id,min(date)start_date,max(date)end_date
from cte2
group by user_id,rnk
```

**EDIT:** without window functions

```
with cte1 as(
   select *,
      case 
        when phase = 'b' then 'end'
        when phase = 'a' and 
           (select top 1 phase from tb t2 where t2.date < t1.date order by date desc) = 'a' 
          then 'no'
        else 'start' end grp
    from tb t1),
cte2 as(
    select *,
       (select top 1 date from cte1 t2 where t2.phase = 'a' and t2.date = t1.date)start_date,
       (select top 1 date from cte1 t2 where t2.phase = 'b' and t2.date = t1.date)end_date
    from cte1 t1
    where grp = 'start' or grp = 'end'),
cte3 as(
    select *
    from cte2
    where start_date is not null
),
cte4 as(
    select *
    from cte2
    where end_date is not null
)
select t1.user_id,t1.start_date,t2.end_date
from cte3 t1

cross apply 

  (select top 1 *
  from cte4 t2
  where t1.date < t2.date) t2
```

***[result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0ede6d268cdedb94a72d05a75a673763)***

Comment: Thank you but I needed a code without window functions